# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable; in google map integration

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I am new to Android development. I am using Eclipse for development. Now I am trying to integrate google map v2 on my app. But I am getting an error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;**.I have integrated this using below steps,

1. Created new project in https://console.developers.google.com/ and enabled google map and generated new android api key using SHA1 fingerprint.
2. Imported `google-play-services_lib` project from `C:\Adt-bundle\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`
3. Added `google-play-services_lib` library project to my Application.
4. Added Permissions `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, INTERNET, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my manifest also added permission for map with my app's package name,

**

```
<permission android:name="myPackageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="myPackageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

**

5. Added api key on the menifest,

   > ```
   > <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   >   android:value="--myapikey--" />
   > ```

When i add MapFragment fragment layout on my layout file I am getting an error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;** Here is the MapFragment fragment I have added

```
> <fragment
>         android:id="@+id/map"
>         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: are you using proguard ?

Comment: I have changed MapFragment  to SupportMapFragment. Then I got 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shidhi.offerzone/com.shidhi.xxxxxx.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio with gradle, in your project's build.gradle file, try making sure that the following line is present in your dependencies{....} to import relevant files into your project:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse for development

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your**

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

**with**

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: I have tried with SupportMapFragment also But I am getting the same error. I had tried this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/get-googlemap-from-mapfragmentsupportma.html

Comment: this was last updated on dec 2012, google map api's has been changed, find a new article which is using google map api v3. and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: I had Tried with SupportMapFragment But I am getting this error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shidhi.offerzone/com.shidhi.xxxxxx.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: I am using Eclipse for Development

Comment: compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'

Comment: these are my dependencies and maps working fine for me.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'